# parallel computing in C and mathematica

Tags: c, wolfram-mathematica, parallel-processing

I have a core i7 lap-top which has 8 processors.

I want to run all these 8 processors simultaneously with the same piece of code (something like kernels in GPU programming) for example:-

```c
// GPU programming code (kernel)
__kernel void set(__global int* list)
    int i = get_global_id();
    list[i] = i;
}
```

I want to do something like this in mathematica but with **C** code not **OpenCL**, or do that with pure C code.

clearly, I want to run a specific piece of code in all cores using mathematica or C.

sorry for being not that clear .. :)

Comment: You could use the pthreads library in C to run a function in a different thread (Each thread uses an available processor). Once that is done you can use MathLink to call your parallelized C function from Mathematica. Is there a particular example of a function that you would like to see done?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to read about [*OpenMP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for ways to utilize all cores in Mathematica, there shouldn't be any need to involve C. Mathematica has [fairly good parallelization functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ParallelComputing.html), for example using [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Parallelize.html):

```
In[1] := Parallelize[Select[Range[9000, 10000], PrimeQ[2^# - 1] &],
                     Method -> "FinestGrained"]
Out[1] = {9689, 9941}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) or [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), both C-based APIs.